# WPF DockPanel: cannot select it to add children

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, intellisense, dockpanel

I have created a few text boxes that have to be added as children to my DockPanel. I have given this DockPanel a name and then when I try in my code to use this name, Intellisense does not give me any results. How do I select DockPanel and then add its children?

I want to select it and add some text boxes to it as its children. For example: `nameLocationPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox());`

This is the top part of my XAML code that contains the DockPanel. It already has some text boxes, but I want to add more in my C# code.

```
        <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lbStyle}" Name="searchList" BorderBrush="#FF898989" BorderThickness="2" MouseUp="searchList_MouseUp" MouseDoubleClick="searchList_MouseDoubleClick" Visibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <DockPanel Name="nameLocationPanel">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text=" "/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Location}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is within a DataTemplate, you can't select it by name at all as it doesn't exist in your Window, it's just a Template definition that will get repeated so there isn't 1 dockpanel but N, N being equal to how many items there are in your listbox and there could well be 0 dockpanels.
What exactly are you trying to achieve? Odds are you're going about it backward.

Comment: I want to select it and add some text boxes to it as its children. For example: `nameLocationPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox());`

Comment: You can't do that, but tell us exactly what your functional goal is (because most likely the solution is NOT to do that). So don't tell me what you're trying to do technically right here, explain what you need to do, when what happens, and why, odds are there is a much better solution that doesn't involve doing anything close to what you have in mind

Comment: I have a `List` that contains text strings. I want to bold parts of certain text strings and this I want to do in my c# code, where I would process every single text string and consequently add it to the ListBox.

Comment: Then you don't want to add or remove textboxes at all, simply bold or unbold the text within, that's a very different issue, sounds to me like you need to switch to MVVM and have for each text a IsBold property, then bind your textbox FontWeight to IsBold with a type converter that converts from true to bold, you definately don't need more textboxes nor to access them individually.

Comment: And if you really want to stick to the raw UI code that you're using, then you need to get rid of the datatemplate concept and simply manage all those items and their textboxes one by one, there's no way to mix datatemplates and binding with non binding logic where you handle things manually without making a total mess out of it.

Comment: The problem with binding to IsBold is that you can only bold whole words and not only parts of them as it is in my case.

Comment: Nonetheless you're going about it wrong, a datatemplate is not what you want if you want to be able to change it, you want to get rid of the data Template and simply add many dockpanels whose children you'll set yourself, but you can't do that with a datatemplate, datatemplates are there for describing something to be displayed and repeated, this isn't your use case here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access to the `DockPanel` because it is a part of a `DataTemplate`. It is generated for every item in your `ListBox` so it is impossible to access to a single instance of it.

To add additional items to the `DockPanel` it is necessary to do it via something like a binding in XAML or a special `UserControl`. But it depend always on the `ListBoxItem`.